# Is an XML response automatically unmarshalled in restTemplate.exchange?

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am using `RestTemplate` to perform an HTTP Get request on a `REST` resource returning an `XML` file.

I have the small piece of code:

```
 restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response.class)
```

The get method returns an `XML`, is it automatically mapped to a Java object `Response`?

The Response class is like the following:

```
  @XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
  public class Response {

     @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
     private String firstName;

     @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
     private String lastName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing this theory did not work, the type in the `exchange` method is of type `String.class` in case of XML, which needs then to be unmarshalled, so that it is processed in `Java` code within the service.